# Is standard, affine infinity of extended reals quite small on the scale of infinities?

Tags: surreal-numbers, singular-values, numerical-systems

Some time ago I had a conversation with a guy who was into surreal numbers and he said that in surreal numbers the affine infinity is quite minor entity compared to the ordinality of natural numbers $\omega$ (although itself affine infinity is not a surreal number, it can be somehow "inserted" between them).

Lets consider possible generalizations of derivatives of otherwise non-differentiable functions. First funtion is peacewise,

$$f_1(x)= \begin{cases}
  x/2-\pi/2, & \mbox{if } x < 0 \\
  x/2+\pi/2,  & \mbox{if } x > 0 \\
  0,  & \mbox{if } x = 0
\end{cases}$$

[image]

We can formally express its derivative at $0$ as $w_1=\pi\delta(0)+1/2$. In this expression the $1/2$ would be regular part and defined as the limit of the derivative from the left and right and the delta part would be responsible for the jump of $\pi$. Since $w_1$ can be formally (via Fourier transform) be represented as $\sum_{k=0}^\infty 1$, this makes a sense of counting natural numbers.

Now consider another function, $f_2(x)=\sqrt[3]{\left| x\right| } \text{sgn}(x)$

[image]

Its derivative at $0$ is infinite as well. Let designate it as $w_2$. It has no jump, thus there is no delta function part.

What can we say about those values $w_1$ and $w_2$? They have different algebraic properties. If we add a linear function $g(x)=5x$ to $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$, $f_1'(0)$ will change: its finite part would increase by $5$. On the other hand $f_2'(0)$ will remain the same. Similarly, if we multiply $f_1(x)$ by a factor, say $5$, both the finite part of $f_1'(0)$ and the jump will increase, while if we multiply $f_2(x)$, $f_2'(0)$ will remain unchanged.

In other words, $w_1$ behaves more like a number: $2w_1\ne w_1$, $w_1+5\ne w_1$ while $w_2$ behaves  weirdly: $a w_2= w_2\, (a>0)$ and $w_2+a=w_2$. These are the properties only known to be satisfied by affine infinity...

On the other hand, we should presume that $w_1>w_2$ because, well, the function $f_1(x)$ grows more at $0$ than $f_2(x)$.

We see that there are two infinite values such that the first one is greater than the second one, but still first one behaves more like a number but the second one behaves more like $\infty$. Can we thus conclude that putting the object named $\infty$ (the one which is invariant regarding addition or multiplication by positive reals) before some other infinite quantities be natural?

**UPDATE**

After thinking of it some more, I think the second example is not perfect here since its delta part is not zero. It is $\frac{\left(\pi  \delta (0)+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{5/3}-\left(\pi  \delta (0)-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{5/3}}{\frac{5}{3}!}$. The power of $\delta(0)$, $2/3$ is too small to make a jump here.

A better example would be a function $f_3(x)=-x \ln \left| x\right|,$

[image]

whose derivative at zero has truly zero delta-part and infinite regular part. Moreover, purely formally we can see that $w_3=f_3'(0)=-\ln 0$, which formally satisfies $-a\ln 0 +b=-\ln (e^b 0^a)=-\ln 0$ (for real $a>0$). These are the qualities usually attributed to $\infty$.

Comment: I'm surprised by your statements that $f'_2(0)$ will remain the same when you add $5x$ to $f_2(x)$ and when you multiply it by$5$. Since these statements are counterintuitive (for me), I'd appreciate an explanation for them.

Comment: @AndreasBlass the limits of $f_2'(x)$ from left and right remain infinite before and after you add or multiply. There is no jump, so the delta-function component also does not change... Yes, I agree, this claim is arguable after all...

Comment: @AndreasBlass and, after thinking of it some more, I think the second example is not perfect here. The delta part of the derivative is not zero. It is $\frac{\left(\pi  \delta (0)+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{5/3}-\left(\pi  \delta (0)-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{5/3}}{\frac{5}{3}!}$ The power of $\delta(0)$, $2/3$ is too small to make a jump here. A better example is function $f_3(x)=-x \ln \left| x\right|$, whose derivative has truly zero delta-part and infinite regular part. And... Indeed we can see that $w_3=\ln 0$, which satisfies ($a \ln 0 +b=\ln (e^b 0^a)=\ln 0$)

Comment: FWIW, Conway had a notion of $\infty$ as a "surreal gap," which is after all the natural numbers but before any infinite quantities. If I recall correctly, the addition rules on surreal gaps are different from the regular surreal numbers, so that you do get the familiar $\infty + n = \infty$ for any natural $n$. So perhaps in that sense, you could identify "affine infinity" with that particular surreal gap (and this seems to be something like the way he was thinking, anyway).

Comment: @MikeBattaglia thanks. This is indeed what I was talking about, and found a graphic model that illustrates the situation.

Comment: @MikeBattaglia are there multiple surreal gaps (it seems, in derivative model, there are multiple, such as $-\ln 0$ and $\ln (-\ln 0)$, which are not equal but obey similar addition/multiplication rules).

Comment: @MikeBattaglia interestingly enough, those "surreal gaps" have addition invariance only regarding real numbers, when added to a transfinte irregular number they do not remain the same. In a sense, one can think of them as irregular numbers whose regular part became infinite, without affecting the irregular part (an analogy in complex numbers would be $i+\infty$).